# How to create multiple entry points and use CommonsChunkPlugin in Ellixir webpack?

Tags: laravel, gulp, webpack, laravel-5.3, laravel-elixir

Is it possible to create multiple entry points (such as `news.js`, `login.js`) and use CommonsChunkPlugin (to nnt iinclude some common code, webpack code, etc. in all entry points) in Elixir with Webpack? Or do I need to create Webpack config file?

I created a simple webpack.config.js

```
var path = require("path");
var CommonsChunkPlugin = require("webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin");

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, "resources/assets"),

    entry: {
        login: "./js/login.js",
        post: "./js/post.js",
        common: "./js/common.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "public/js"),
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new CommonsChunkPlugin({
            filename: "common.js",
            name: "common"
        })
    ]
};
```

but what is the correct way to make Elixir use it?

Looks like it still needs a file path, that is `mix.webpack()` throws error about undefined.

`mix.webpack('')`  fails during production build with this error:

```
Starting 'webpack'...

Hmm, not sure how to compress this type of file. Stick with CSS or JavaScript files!
```

`mix.webpack(['post.js', 'login.js', 'common.js'])` and `mix.webpack('*.js')` seems to work but looks like it was not intended to be used like this because destination output looks weird (though `all.js` is not created)

```
┌───────────────┬───────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ Task          │ Summary                       │ Source Files                   │ Destination        │
├───────────────┼───────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│ mix.webpack() │ 1. Transforming ES2015 to ES5 │ resources\assets\js\common.js  │ public\js\all.js   │
│               │ 2. Writing Source Maps        │ resources\assets\js\login.js   │                    │
│               │ 3. Applying Minification      │ resources\assets\js\post.js    │                    │
│               │ 4. Saving to Destination      │                                │
```